# Provide extra information to Flask's app.logger

Tags: python, flask

The [default debug log format](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.debug_log_format) for Flask 0.10 is

```
debug_log_format =
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------\n%
%(levelname)s in %(module)s [%(pathname)s:%(lineno)d]:\n%(message)s
\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------'
```

How do I change it to this:

```
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------\n%
work_id %(levelname)s in %(module)s [%(pathname)s:%(lineno)d]:\n%(message)s
\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------'
```

where `work_id` is a randomly generated UUID for each request.

If the logger is created by myself, I can just use a `logging.LoggerAdapter` and provide the extra information as a dict `{'work_id': some_uuid}`, then I can access it in the log record using `record.work_id`.

But the `app.logger` is created by [`create_logger()` in Flask's`logging.py`](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/33534bb4a9937e6faba5ecec4586519f453369b6/flask/logging.py#L50), do I have to modify the Flask source to achieve what I want?

I also thought just override `app.logger` with my own logger, like `app.logger = my_logger`, it doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 12):

**Via Flask.debug_log_format**

Just do this:

```
app.debug = True
app.debug_log_format = """-------------------------------------------------------------------------
%(worker_id)s (levelname)s in %(module)s [%(pathname)s:%(lineno)d]:\n%(message)s
-------------------------------------------------------------------------"""
app.logger.log("test", extra={"worker_id": request.your_uuid_property)
```

Example:

```
import logging
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

# please replace "request.uuid" with your actual property
log = lambda msg: app.logger.info(msg, extra={'worker_id': "request.uuid" })

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    log("hello world")
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.debug_log_format = """-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %(worker_id)s in %(module)s [%(pathname)s:%(lineno)d]:
    %(message)s
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------"""
    app.debug = True
    log("hello world")
    app.run()
```

**Via Handler and Formatter of standard logging module**

Flask uses logging any way, so you can use [logging.Handler](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#handlers) and [logging.Formatter](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#formatters) to achieve outside Flask. A generic example can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging). Advanced topic of logging configuration can be found in [the doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#module-logging.config) and in the [cookbook](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html)

A tailored example regarding your question is:

```
import logging
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

class CustomFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def format(self, record):
        record.worker_id = "request.uuid" # replace this with your variable 
        return super(CustomFormatter,self).format(record)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    app.logger.info("hello world")
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    custom_format = """-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %(worker_id)s in %(module)s [%(pathname)s:%(lineno)d]:
    %(message)s
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------"""
    app.debug = True
    ch = logging.StreamHandler()
    ch.setFormatter(CustomFormatter(fmt=custom_format))
    app.logger.addHandler(ch)
    app.logger.debug("hello world")
    app.run()
```

**Via overriding logging.Logger class**

The same objective can be achieved by override the default logger class. Combining the [flask request context stack](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-extended-logging), you would be able to get your own field in the log:

```
import logging
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
from flask import _request_ctx_stack

CUSTOM_FORMAT = """-------------------------------------------------------------------------
%(worker_id)s in %(module)s [%(pathname)s:%(lineno)d]:
%(message)s
-------------------------------------------------------------------------"""

class MyLogger(logging.Logger):
    def makeRecord(self, name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func=None, extra=None):
        ctx = _request_ctx_stack.top
        custom_extra = dict(
            worker_id="request.uuid"
        )
        if ctx is not None:
            url = ctx.request.url # please replace this with your own field
            custom_extra["worker_id"] = url

        if extra is not None:
            extra.update(custom_extra)
        else:
            extra = custom_extra
        return super(MyLogger,self).makeRecord(name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func=func, extra=extra)

logging.setLoggerClass(MyLogger)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    app.logger.info("hello world")
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.debug_log_format = CUSTOM_FORMAT
    app.debug = True
    app.logger.debug("hello world")
    app.run()
```

Comment: How do I pass the `work_id` to log record, because without passing it to log record, formatter cannot access it, which means your first solution didn't work at all.

Comment: That would work. But I'm looking for a way to modify the `app.logger` directly, so I don't have to import these wrapped log functions as globals. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Didn't think of formatter, thanks for the idea. But... it won't work well, because I have to set a formatter for each request (work_id is hard coded in the formater) and I don't want an extra log handler. I'm just gonna use your first solution, namely, wrap the app.logger with a function, define several functions, one for each level, at the top of my source.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another example using a custom `Formatter`. Thanks to @chfw and to [this](https://gist.github.com/danielrichman/1acbbd66166ab857c404)

I like the use of `flask.has_request_context()` here, so that logging doesn't get in the way of unit tests

```
import logging
from logging import StreamHandler
import flask
from flask import Flask, g, request

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
app = flask.Flask(__name__)


class CustomFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def format(self, record):
        record.uuid = None
        if flask.has_request_context():
            record.uuid = g.uuid if hasattr(g, 'uuid') else None
            record.path = request.path
            record.endpoint = request.endpoint
            record.remote_addr = request.remote_addr
        return super(CustomFormatter, self).format(record)

custom_format = '''%(levelname)s %(name)s %(uuid)s %(path)s %(endpoint)s %(remote_addr)s  %(message)s'''
handler = StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(CustomFormatter(fmt=custom_format))
logger.addHandler(handler)


with app.test_request_context():
    g.uuid = 'foo'
    logger.fatal('help')
```