# How to log in Flask

Tags: flask

I'm running a flask app. I'd like to write out a log.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

print() statements don't work. (possibly because I'm running flask in a docker container?) Somewhere on the web I found this syntax:

```
app.logger.info('successful query')
```

Which works except the output is fairly bulky:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO in app [/usr/src/app/app.py:187]:
successful query
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You can imagine how a bunch of these in a row are kind of annoying. You printing 4 lines ever time you could print one.

Is there a simple, easy way to log arbitrary messages in flask on one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the best way to do this is to use [`app.logger.info`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.logger) (or any one of [app.logger's functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger)), but change the format with [`app.debug_log_format`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.debug_log_format)

[This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27775026/provide-extra-information-to-flasks-app-logger) has more details.

Answer (score 2):

I think the [Formatter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#formatter-objects) is the best way to do that. 
For example:

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

formatter = logging.Formatter("[%(asctime)s] %(message)s")

handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler('path/to/file.log', when='midnight', 
                                   interval=1, backupCount=5)
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
app.logger.addHandler(handler)
```

*asctime* and *message* are predefined [attributes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes).

Comment: could you please provide a sample to log.

Comment: Just found out: app.logger.info('search button clicked')
You cant call it from __main__ . learned the hard way.